# Saving and playing an audio file

Tags: java, android, audio

I am trying to save and play an audio file. Saving looks as it works fine but I have a problem with playing that file.

This is what I have tried:

```java
// Save the audio
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir() + "/output.mp3")) {
    System.out.println(getFilesDir());
    out.write(audioContents.toByteArray());
    System.out.println("Audio content written to file \"output.mp3\"");
}

// Play the audio
String path = getFilesDir() + "/output.mp3";
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

And this is what I get:

> I/System.out: /data/user/0/ch.yourclick.kitt/files Audio content written to file "output.mp3"
> W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
> W/System.err: at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)

How can I simply play that audio file?

Comment: You forgot an out.close();

Comment: `recorder.setOutputFile(path);` Dont know... but if you wanna play a file i would think you would need an input file like: `recorder.setInputFile(path);`

Comment: @blackapps if I add it, Android Studio tells me *Redundant 'close()'*. And the method `setInputFile()` does not exist in `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: You better listen to me then to Android Studio. Close it.

Comment: `OutputStream out` Why not `FileOutputStream out` ?

Comment: @blackapps I have closed it now and also tried it with `FileOutputStream` instead but still the same error.

Comment: Your problem does not appear to be with the file, but with your `setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)` call. Also note that `MediaRecorder` is for *recording* media, not *playing* media.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for this info. Is there another way to play that audio?

Comment: `MediaPlayer` plays media. And, at least initially, you could use Android Studio's Device File Explorer to copy the `output.mp3` file off of your test device and onto your development machine, to make sure that it seems to be correct.